# show/hide object based on checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

I have a page that include a set of checkboxes, each with a value that is dynamically generated, so it changes with each page rendering. A sample looks like this:

```
<fieldset id="P163_PROFILES" tabindex="-1" class="checkbox_group">
   <input type="checkbox" id="P163_PROFILES_0" name="p_v01" value="264" checked="checked">
   <input type="checkbox" id="P163_PROFILES_1" name="p_v01" value="2356" checked="checked">
</fieldset>
```

I then have `<div class="264">` and `<div class="2356">` tags throughout the rest of the page in a calendar layout where the DIV class matches on of the input values. My question is this. If a user un/checks one of the input boxes, I want to hide/show the DIVs with the matching classes. Since I'm new to jQuery, I'm struggling with the logic to identify the input object that has changed and then use it's value to alter the appropriate DIV objects. Here is the code I have thus far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( '[id^=P163_PROFILES_]' ).click(function(){
   var pClass = '.'+$(this).val();
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(pClass).show;
      } else {
         $(pClass).hide;
      }
});
</script>
```

Am I even close?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2):

You're actually very close! You're forgetting `()` after the `show()` and `hide()` methods:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(pClass).show();
} else {
    $(pClass).hide();
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3dVV/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want

```
$('input[id^="P163_PROFILES_"]').click(function(event){
    var pClass = '.'+$(event.target).val();
    if ($(event.target).is(':checked')) {
        $(pClass).show();
    } else {
        $(pClass).hide();
    }
});
```

You probably don't have to worry about bubbling with such a specific selector, so you can just use:

```
$('input[id^="P163_PROFILES_"]').click() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.'+$this.val()).toggle($this.is(':checked));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply that code. First, I would advise against using the `click()` event, the preferred event would be `change()`

First, let's assume everything starts out in the desired state. You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( 'input[id^="P163_PROFILES_"]' ).change(function(){
   var pClass = '.'+$(this).val();
   $(pClass).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Toggle will simply toggle the visible of the selected element.

If you need to toggle based on state then do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( 'input[id^="P163_PROFILES_"]' ).change(function(){
    var pClass = '.'+$(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
         $(pClass).show();
    else
         $(pClass).hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can further simplify it if you query for the fieldsets inputchildren instead of querying on id's starting with. Might simplify your code gen as well since that might mean you don't have to generate ID's for the inputs.

Also, you're overusing jQuery. Often "this" will have all the things you need, and you don't need to add overhead by wrapping it in a jQuery. No reason not to use this.checked and this.value directly afaik.

```
$('#P163_PROFILES > input' ).change(function(){
    if (this.checked)
        $('.'+this.value).show();
    else
        $('.'+this.value).hide();
    //Or toggle if you know the initial state is in sync with the target
    //and nothing else changes the show/hide of those targets.
    //$('.'+this.value).toggle();
});
```