# show or hide div, dependet on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a checkbox and under the checkbox a div area, where i wanna show a dropdown and another checkboxes. This area i wanna just show when the first checkbox is checked.

I already try it with style.display and it works half. I can display the second area when i check the checkbox, but if i uncheck it doesn´t hide again. Same if I try with jquery (posted both)

```js
//function F2

function functpe() {

  var tpe = document.getElementById("tpe");


  if (tpe.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("doing").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("doing").style.display = "none";
  }
}


function functpe() {

  var tpe = $("#doing");


  if (tpe.checked == true) {
    $("#doing").css({
      "display": "block"
    });

  } else {
    $("#doing").css({
      "display": "block"
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
  <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tpe" value="tpe" onchange="functpe()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="tpe">tpe</label>
</div>
<div id="doing" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tpe" style="width: 170px;">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n1" value="n1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n1">n1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n2" value="n2" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n2">n2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n3" value="n3" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n3">n3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone have an idea for me

Comment: As you've tagged this jquery:  `$("#doing").show(tpe.checked);`

Comment: How are you triggering `functpe()`?  Have you checked the value of `tpe.checked` (console/alert/debug-step)?  Is it always `true`?

Comment: I found your code in the edit - just needed first line to be indented with 4 or more spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Show-Hide DIV based on Checkbox Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444292/jquery-show-hide-div-based-on-checkbox-value) and [Jquery Show / Hide based on checkbox status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721180) and [How to show/hide an element on checkbox checked/unchecked states using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307323) and [Show/Hide with Checkbox using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766875) and [show/hide object based on checkbox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this with JQuery `Toggle`

```js
$('.initialOne').change(function() {
  $('#doing').slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
  <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox initialOne" type="checkbox" id="tpe" value="tpe">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="tpe">tpe</label>
</div>
<div id="doing" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tpe" style="width: 170px;">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n1" value="n1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n1">n1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n2" value="n2" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n2">n2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n3" value="n3" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n3">n3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with only CSS. You just need to tweak a little bit order to make `#doing` a sibling of checkbox ;)
[Here's an example](https://codepen.io/Rafi-R/pen/omwMqW)

```css
.doing {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .doing {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I edit the inline example text to use pure CSS to avoid any need for SASS processing. Codepen.io example link still uses SASS, though, if you have/want that.

Comment: Personally it doesn't show again, the second part doesn't works (with `type=checkbox`) even if I change the way to check the input, it's the same; Can you more explain how `~` works here, and how the input is choosed ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `toggle` method provided by the jQuery API

```js
$('#hide').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#post').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label for="hide">Hide</label>
<input id="hide" type="checkbox" checked/>

<p id="post">Now you see me</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check below code to toggle(show/hide) dive when click on check box.

```
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
    content
</div> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
            $('#autoUpdate').toggle()
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried your code and it seems to work fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8nfx4g2/

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
  <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tpe" value="tpe" onchange="functpe()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="tpe">tpe</label>
</div>
<div id="doing" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tpe" style="width: 170px;">
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n1" value="n1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n1">n1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n2" value="n2" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n2">n2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:20px">
    <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="n3" value="n3" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="n3">n3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function functpe() {

    var tpe = document.getElementById("tpe");


    if (tpe.checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("doing").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("doing").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

</script>
```

Please confirm if you are getting any errors in the console?